# _Dist_type not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, stl, scope, g++

I've been tasked with getting some old code working. It's dated from 2006 and I believe it was written in visual studio. I get this error when compiling with g++ 4.5.2 using ming32 on a windows machine and I get the same error compiling with g++ 4.1.2 on a unix machine(not sure what flavor)

"_Dist_type was not declared in this scope"

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<class ReturnType, class RandomIterator, class _Ty> inline
ReturnType interpolate(RandomIterator _F, RandomIterator _L, const _Ty& _V, RandomIterator _F2)
{
  return _Dist_type(_F);
}

class Interpolator
{
public:
  double interp(const std::vector<double>& xValues, const std::vector<double>& yValues, 
    const double x0) const
  {
    //1-D interpolation
    return interpolate<double>(xValues.begin(), xValues.end(), x0, yValues.begin());
  }
};
```

I've tried googling for _dist_Type, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of information out there. I did find one source, but I'm not sure how much it can help. http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-1040/STL-Iterator.htm

It's my understanding that _Dist_type is part of a very old version of the STL library which neither build machine has. How could I solve this? I'm not even sure what the function does.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's certainly hard to imagine that it did anything useful considering it discards 3 of the 4 arguments passed in...

Comment: I culled the example down to the minimum required to produce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_Dist_type` is an internal implementation detail used by Visual Studio's standard library. Names starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved by the implementation and must *never* be called directly from user code.

You'll have to figure out what that function does and duplicate the functionality in a portable manner. If you're lucky you might find that there is a function in the standard library that already implements this functionality and you can just replace the call.

**EDIT:**
Both Visual Studio 2005 & 2010 have `_Dist_type` defined as

```
template<class _Iter> inline
typename iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type
*_Dist_type(_Iter)
{   // return distance type from arbitrary argument
  return (0);
}
```

So it is just returning a value of `0` of type `std::iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::difference_type`

Comment: After fixing the problem, you should go find the person who implemented that function and kick his ass; then explain to him the importance of using defined interfaces.

Comment: haha yeah.. wish I could.   Thanks, I think this will get me to a solution pretty quick :D